# Change/control property order in CosmosDb document when saving it

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

This might seem silly, but it's irritating.I'm using C# and `cosmosdb sdk`.

I have a document in db, lets say employee, and a corresponding Employee-class in my code.

```
employee
{
   id: "123",
   firstName : "Hans",
   age : 23
}
```

and when updating the Employee-class in code to

```
public class Employee
{
   public string Id{get;set}
   public string FirstName{get;set}
   public string LastName{get;set} // new
   public int Age{get;set}
   public Dictionary<string, object> OtherProperties {get;set} // also new
}
```

...then reading an existing document in code (GetById) and Upserting in again my document looks like this

```
employee
{  
   otherProperties : null,
   id: "123"
   firstName : "Hans",
   lastName : null,
   age : 23
}
```

What irritates me is that the **otherProperties**-property is now the first one. `lastName` (which was also added) happens to be exactly where it is in the class. Can I fix this somehow?

I have tested to have the property in another order in the class and also tried to change datatype to string, no difference.

Comment: There's really no concept of property-ordering - at least, when stored. It's an unordered set of key/value pairs. And ordering has no impact on mapping a document to a class.

Comment: ok, Im aware of that it doesnt make any difference ,just irritating... I just wanted to be sure. Im leaving this Q open, in case someone have stumbled upon a fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you explain from a functional side what problem the order of properties generates?

You can decorate the class using the Newtonsoft.Json's `Order` on the `JsonProperty`: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm but aside from a cosmetic result, there isn't much of a functional difference.

Something like:

```
public class Employee
{
   [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
   public string Id{get;set}
   
   [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
   public string FirstName{get;set}
   
   [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
   public string LastName{get;set}
   
   [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
   public int Age{get;set}
   
   [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
   public Dictionary<string, object> OtherProperties {get;set}
}
```

Comment: There is no functional benefit as such. It just annoys me  and others that look into the db through azure quering api, since it easier to overview a document with a familiar "visual" structure. Ill have a look at your suggestion soon.

Comment: Worked, thanks! (just by numbering the one property,it was added last (except for cosmosdb internal properties) which suits me. Im just going through the db once with this attribute to add that property and then removing it the attribute after that